# plumpとclssで要素内の属性値を取得したい

Tags: common-lisp

現在Common Lispで簡単なWebクローラを作成しています。
plumpとclssを使ってhtmlをパースするところまではできたのですが、要素内で指定されている属性値の取得方法がわかりません。

例えば以下のようなhtmlがあった時に、

```
<a href="hoge.html" title="fuga">リンク</a>
```

`href`で指定されている"hoge.html"と、`title`で指定されている"fuga"を取得したい場合、どのように書けばいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clss:select`でも色々できるとは思いますが、`plump:attribule`で抜き出すことが可能なようです。

- [PLUMP-DOM:ATTRIBUTE](http://shinmera.github.io/plump/#PLUMP-DOM:ATTRIBUTE)

#### 利用例:

```
(let* ((dat (plump:parse "<a href=\"hoge.html\" title=\"hoge\">リンク</a><a href=\"fuga.html\">リンク</a>" ))
       (a-tags (clss:select "a" dat)))
  (loop :for a :across a-tags
        :for href  := (plump:attribute a "href")
        :for title := (plump:attribute a "title")
        :do (format T
                    "~&title=~A href=~A~%"
                    (or title "<none>")
                    (or href "<none>")
                    )))
;>> title=hoge href=hoge.html
;>> title=<none> href=fuga.html
;=> nil
```

属性をまとめて全部取得ならば、`plump:attributes`が使えるようです。

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)

(let* ((dat (plump:parse "<a href=\"hoge.html\" title=\"hoge\">リンク</a><a href=\"fuga.html\">リンク</a>" ))
       (a-tags (clss:select "a" dat)))
  (loop :for a :across a-tags
        :count a :into cnt
        :do (format T
                    "~&~D:~S~%"
                    cnt
                    (alexandria:hash-table-alist (plump:attributes a))
                    )))
;>> 1:(("href" . "hoge.html") ("title" . "hoge"))
;>> 2:(("href" . "fuga.html"))
```